# Cannot install module Unicode::Map8 using cpan on CentOS 5

Tags: perl, unicode, cpan

I am trying to install [`Unicode::Map8`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Map8) module using cpan on CentOS5  with `2.6.18-371.9.1.el5 kernel`. So when I do `cpan> install Unicode::Map8` as `sudo` I get the following result:

```
Running install for module Unicode::Map8
Running make for G/GA/GAAS/Unicode-Map8-0.13.tar.gz
Is already unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Unicode-Map8-0.13
Has already been processed within this session
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/callback....ok                                                             
t/compat......ok                                                             
t/map8........dubious                                                        
    Test returned status 0 (wstat 11, 0xb)
t/unistr......ok                                                             
Failed Test Stat Wstat Total Fail  Failed  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t/map8.t       0    11    ??   ??       %  ??
Failed 1/4 test scripts, 75.00% okay. 0/6 subtests failed, 100.00% okay.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
/usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
Running make install
make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

The perl version is `v5.8.8`.
I tried this on my machine and on server that runs the same config.
Any Idea what might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode::Map8 is available as a pre-built package for Centos in the [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). Once you have configured your system to use EPEL (and that's well worth doing as they have a lot more CPAN modules that the standard Centos repos) you can install it using yum.

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Unicode-Map8
```

Comment: worked nicely, thank you. but I still wonder what was the problem when I tried to do it through cpan.

Comment: Looks like one of the tests failed. You could download the tarball and run that test in verbose mode (`prove -v`) to get more info. And then, perhaps, pass a bug report back to the maintainer.